# c++ Doxygen \example and description

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am using `doxygen version 1.8.8` to build the C++ documentation. I included a detailed description of my templated class as follows:

```
/** A test class. Detailed description of the test class
 *  Usage:
 *  @code
 *    test a;
 *  @endcode
 */
template<>
class test
{
  //some class
};
```

and want to include an example to a file called `testexample.cpp`

if I just put the `@example` at the end of the detailed description the detailed description is applied to the example.

```
/** A test class. Detailed description of the test class
 *  Usage:
 *  @code
 *    test a;
 *  @endcode
 *  @example testexample.cpp
 *  An example of the test class.
 */
template<>
class test
{
  //some class
};
```

How can I have a detailed description of the class AND a link to a file of an example which shows the usage of the class in a detailed manner?

In the doxygen example of `@example` they reference an example to a member variable. And the example is linked to this member function. This is not what I wish to achieve in this case since I want to show how this class can be used in a fully working example and not only in a usage instruction.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: 1.8.8, added it to the question.

Comment: `\example` has just one argument, the filename. please correct and check again. Version 1.8.8 is a bit old the current version is 1.8.14.

Comment: @BeatScherrer: "*This is not what I wish to achieve in this case since I want to show how this class can be used in a fully working example and not only in a usage instruction.*" I don't know what you mean by that. The sample code they provide is exactly that: sample code. You can make the code as big as you like. So what exactly is wrong with doing things Doxygen's way?

Comment: @NicolBolas The example they provide is for a member function explicitly and not an example of using the class and hence is contained in the `example()` section of the documentation (see doxygen example output). My goal is to get such an example for the whole class. But since the Class already has a description I can't simply add the `\example` at the end of the description, which results in taking over the description of the class to the description of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having received the answer from nicol, I achieved what I was looking for in the following way:

```
/** A test class. Detailed description of the test class
 *  Usage:
 *  @code
 *    test a;
 *  @endcode
 */
template<>
class test
{
  //some class
};
/**@example TestExample.cpp
 * Simple example of how to use the test class
 */
```

I tried it this way already but because I did not set the `EXAMPLE_PATH` in the `Doxyfile` the example could not have been found and thus the `@example` tag became useless. After having specified the `EXAMPLE_PATH` everything worked as expected.

Comment: You could put it *before* the class too. Or in a completely different file. The connection between the example and `test` is made because `TestExample.cpp` actually uses the class `test` in its code, not because of its proximity to the class.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok this makes sense and would mean that the `@example` block would best be in the example file instead of the class definition?

Comment: Where you put it is wherever you feel is best. My point is that it's important to realize that where you put it doesn't matter in terms of how it gets linked to the various documented entities in your code.

Answer (score 6):

The way Doxygen works with examples is that a code example is a separate page from regular documentation. So `@example` is like `@page` or `@module`: it takes the entire documentation block and applies it to the example's page. And any documented entity that gets used within that example code will have its documentation augmented with links *to* that example.

So what you need is a standalone documentation block like this:

```
/**
 *  @example testexample testexample.cpp
 *  An example of the test class.
 */
```

This doesn't have to be in the same file as your `test` class.

Comment: Also have a look at commands like `\snippet...`, `\verbinclude` and `\include...`

Comment: In the example of `\example` the example is linked directly to the class. How is this linking achieved if I don't need to include it in the class declaration?

Comment: I think you are pointing to the automatic link options of doxygen.

Comment: I put the `@example` block at the end of the class definition and now it works fine. I believed I tried it this way but seems like i missed something, will write an answer with what I did in the end.